# Open SSH connection on specific network interface (JSch)

Tags: networking, interface, ssh, jsch

How can I configure JSch client to communicate using network interface other than default one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that it is possible. I have the same requirement and checked the source code provided along with JSch. The plain Socket is created without a local address or port.

Comment: I even forgot I've asked that question. I've already found that out and dropped the idea. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the [SocketFactory](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/SocketFactory.html) interface to create a custom socket with a specified source interface, and then use [`session.setSocketFactory(...)`](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#setSocketFactory%28com.jcraft.jsch.SocketFactory%29) to plug it into your JSch session.

Comment: Ok...have undeleted this because another user assures me that is is the correct answer, even if posted twice.

Comment: @Kev: Thanks for the undeletion. I added some links. (The [duplicate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12152462) looks like posted to the wrong question, though.)